# When do answers get replaced with a "This answer was marked as abusive or spam" message?

Tags: discussion, moderation

In some circumstances, answers get replaced with a message saying ([example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/87908/324) for high rep users)

> This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not
>   shown - you can see the revision history for details.
>   locked by Community♦ Feb 12 at 1:00
>   deleted as spam or offensive Feb 12 at 1:00
>   by Community♦

However, [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88046/can-a-mixed-muslim-unmarried-couple-share-hotel-rooms-in-indonesia/88242#88242) (also only available for high rep users) was flagged with "Rude and abusive", the flag was regarded as helpful, and the answer was deleted by a diamond mod (not Community), but hasn't had its text replaced.

What's the difference between the two moderation actions? Was the former automatic as a result of receiving a lot of flags, or is there some "nuke the answer" switch a diamond mod can use against an answer, which was used against the former but not against the latter?

Comment: If you'd like the content to be hidden flag it for moderator attention explaining why. That's what I usually do.

Comment: You're right! Don't know what happened there. Maybe I clicked on the first link instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A post (question or answer) gets replaced with "not shown" message if it was **deleted via a flag**. This happens when a post gets either

- 6 flags in total of the "spam" and "rude/abusive" kinds
- 1 such flag from a moderator

In all other cases, the content is still shown to 10K users: for example, if there were fewer than 6 flags and a moderator opted to click *delete* rather than *flag*.

Reference: [Post content not removed after spam/offensive flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272642#272643) (where some discussion of possible changes to the system was had; but to my knowledge, no such changes were made yet).